# drf-yasg Django restframework Swagger Page return blank page with django login a href link

Tags: django, swagger, drf-yasg

Hi I try to add to my project swagger but it return 401 error , please help me about it

it is my router

```
from . import router
    schema_view = get_schema_view(
        openapi.Info(
            title='EduOn API',
            description="EduOn API",
            default_version='v1',
            terms_of_service='https://www.google.com/policies/terms/',
            contact=openapi.Contact(email="algoritmgateway@gmail.com"),
            license=openapi.License(name='EduOn License'),
        ),
        public=True,
        permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,)
    )
```

register my routers:

```
urlpatterns += router.router.urls
```

in urlpatterns inside list :

```
#documents
    url(r'^swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name='schema-json'),
    url(r'^swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    url(r'^redoc/$', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
```

and register in INSTALLED_APPS

I get my expecct output in onluy localhist:8000
but if i restart nginx and enter production website it get this output (
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqCXw.png)

Comment: Davronbek Boltayev how were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced the same issue. If you collected static files before you will need to collect static files again for swagger ui.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```